# How to count over 255 in pic assembly?

Tags: assembly, counter, pic

I need to count bytes that come from serial port, and do something when they are over 300, but a memory address only can count from 0 to 255, and i cant figuring  how can count over 255

sorry if is a dumb question, but i have no experience in asm development...

PD: i know i can program pics in C but i'm editing some software previously made for someone else  at work

pic16f77

```
COUNT
    INCF COUNTRX,1
    MOVLW D'255'  ;need these value over 300 
    MOVWF VALUE         
    MOVF COUNTRX,W
    SUBWF VALUE,W
    BTFSS STATUS,0      
    GOTO ITSVALUE
    GOTO NOTITSVALUE
```

Comment: See [this page](http://www.pic-projects.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57:multi-byte-addition-a-subtraction&catid=38:arithmetic&Itemid=57) for examples of multi-byte addition and subtraction in PIC assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a several ways how to do it, but you need additional variable to store result larger than 255:

1)Use an extra ninth bit, so you can count up to 511 (2^9 - 1).

```
;Data memory definition
    SomeVariable  SET 1 
    #define  CountRxBit9        SomeVariable, n    ;define CountRxBit9 bit vhere n is in range 0..7
;... 
;Clear variable
    CLRF   COUNTRX
    BCF    CountRxBit9
;...
;increment COUNTRX     
    INCF   COUNTRX,1
    BTFSC  STATUS, 2     ;Test Zero flag after increment
    BSF    CountRxBit9   ;Set ninth bit if ZERO is one
```

2)Use an extra byte, so you can count up to 65535 (2^16 - 1).

```
;Data memory definition
    HighCountRxBit   SET 1 
;... 
;Clear variable
    CLRF   COUNTRX
    CLRF   HighCountRx
;...
;increment COUNTRX     
    INCF   COUNTRX,1
    BTFSC  STATUS, 2     ;Test Zero flag after increment
    INCF   HighCountRx, 1;Increment high byte of counter if ZERO is one
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use additional register in order to count to more that 255. The following code should work:

counter = (COUNTERX2*255 + COUNTERX)

```
COUNT
    BTFSC COUNTRX2,0 ; helper variable to hold more significant byte of counter
    GOTO OVER255     ; if COUNTERX2 is not zero, it means counter > 255
    INCF COUNTRX,1   ; if counter is less than 256, increment it
            ; COUNTERX is zero at this point only 
            ; if it was earlier 255 and was just incremented
    BTFSC STATUS,Z   
    INCF COUNTRX2,1  ; if COUNTERX is zero, increment COUNTERX2
    GOTO NOTITSVALUE

OVER255
    INCF COUNTRX,1   ; again increment COUTERX to continue counting
    MOVLW D'44'      ; = 300 - 256
    MOVWF VALUE
    MOVF COUNTRX,W
            ; 44 - COUNTERX, effectively 300 - (COUNTERX2*255 + COUNTERX)
    SUBWF VALUE,W    
    BTFSC STATUS,Z
    GOTO ITSVALUE
    GOTO NOTITSVALUE
```

I tested it with MPLABX Simulator and it works. It could not be optimal, becouse i am a beginner at assembly programming.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! it should work just fine, but i'm executing the increment inside of an interruption and made several arithmetic, and when i use addwf or subwf and return to the original interruption subroutine, maths starts behaving creepily  XD something. May be because arithmetic functions affects the DC bit on STATUS register.

Comment: Arithmetic functions affects DC, C and Z bits in status register, but you have them in your original code. Try push STATUS register at the beginning of counter code execution and pop it at the end. Also make sure, that additional file registers you use are not in use of other parts of code (or also use push and pop).